# Failing to connect to a web server with Java

Tags: java, http, connection, fiddler

I got a strange task: to connect to webserver using Java even though I'm a php programmer. I used to program Java back at the university but it's been good few years since.

I took a code sample from stack-overflow. It runs fine, no compilation errors no exceptions, but, I don't see any outgoing connection when I sniff with Fiddler, and my server side script doesn't see any incoming connections either.

Any ideas of what can be wrong? Or, how do I debug this situation?

```
String urlParameters = "param1=a&param2=b&param3=c";
String request = "http://example.com/index.php";
URL url = new URL(request); 
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
connection.setUseCaches (false);

DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
connection.disconnect();
```

Comment: Try adding `System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
System.out.println(connection.getResponseMessage());` before calling disconnect to see what the server response is - maybe the URL is wrong

Comment: Fiddler won't show traffic unless you proxy through it. Ensure you `-DproxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DproxyPort=8888`

Comment: @Fuzzyfelt, where should this line go?

Comment: Ok, excellent guidance, thank you both. getResponseMessage() taught me that the connection was successful after all and there was a problem on the server side, and I fixed it. Indeed fiddler didn't show the outgoing connection even though the server side does register it now

Comment: @shealtiel Java has a notion of System Properties, which are similar to environment variables. Certain packages can be configured by setting these system properties. System Properties can be set programmatically with `System.setProperty(propName)` or as -D arguments on the command line. So in this case, add `-DproxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DproxyPort=8888` to your `java` command line

Comment: A strange phenomena: apparently, adding the line connection.getResponseCode(); before connection.disconnect(); causes the connection to actually be established. Very strange, but omitting this line makes the code fail. Thoughts?

Comment: Is Java simply garbage collecting the request before it's sent if you don't have a blocking operation (e.g. getResponseCode()) that waits for the response?